# Identifying data sources within SSIS through SSMS in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis

As a company we have grown and we are now moving a couple of SQL Server 2016 databases over to a new server. We have SSIS packages that run off the databases that we are moving from server 1 to server 2.

Is there a way to easily identify using SSMS which SSIS packages use the current server and databases we are moving? Some of the old SSIS packages don't have documentation so we are trying to avoid physically opening up all the SSIS packages.  We would prefer to identify the SSIS packages that are impacted.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not aware of a good way to find out via SQL Server.  But a SSIS package is basically XML underneath.  So, you could just have a process that scans through each package in search for the connection strings.  That's my suggestion.

Comment: Also, assuming that your packages aren't using any dynamic/variable connection strings.  Also, do your SSIS packages use any sort of SSIS Configurations?  If not, I'd suggest moving toward using it.  It would help with future moves if all packages used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my solutions on the top of my head. I'm not an expert by any means so don't be surprised if someone comes up with something better.

1. In SSMS, you can view the data sources being utilized by a
   package by... Object Explorer > SQL Server Agent > Jobs > (Your Job) > Steps > Edit... > Data Sources (Tab)

   Here, you can view the data sources of your package. This is
   slightly faster than opening all your SSIS packages; but, it isn't a
   great solution either.
2. Conversely, recognize that .dtsx files are simply plain text
   files. You can scan keywords within all of them using a number of
   different scripts (PowerShell, Python, SSIS package w/ a Script
   Task, etc.)

   What you can use depends on the tech stack that your organization
   supports but I imagining Googling for such a program/script would
   not be difficult.
3. If you are utilizing SQL Server configurations in your packages
   and you consistently do so for every package, you can query the
   [SSIS_Configurations].[dbo].[SSIS Configurations]

NOTE: Solution (1) and (2) do not take configurations into account.

Hopefully, some of these solutions are helpful to you. I would be interested in an efficient means to do this without delving into scripts as well.

Comment: Thank you!  This will get us through.